# Is it necessary to delete previously generated objects in random level generation? (In Unity)

Tags: memory-management, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am making a game in unity. In the game the level randomly generates new objects in the scene as the player moves forward.

So is it necessary to delete/destroy the previously generated objects as the player moves forward?

Will it improve memory usage?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are a beginner and you just messing around with Unity3D, then generate and destroy objects. If you plan on releasing any game, that is no no. Don't do it!

> So is it necessary to delete/destroy the previously generated objects
>   as the player moves forward?
>
> Will it improve memory usage?

It is necessary to delete /destroy object if you generate a new one or you would run out of memory.
But generating and deleting/destroying GameObjects will slow down your game because this will be invoking the garbage collector.

The way of doing this properly is to use something called **Object Pooling**.
You have to make your own Object Pooling class.

Its long to explain but I will try to keep it short.

Object pooling works by **re-using** game object instead of **Instantiating/Generating** new objects and **Destroying** old one.

There are many ways to do this but I will talk about the way I do it.

1. Find out the max objects that is suppose to be in the scene. 
   Lets day that your gun uses 7 bullets, You need 20 bullets in the pool for your FPS game.
2. Before the game starts, create 20 bullets in the scene and hide them by disabling all of them.
3. In `start` or `Awake` function, **get** all of the **properties** of the bullets that would **change** when you **shoot** it. The **transform** and **rotation/quaternion** are one of the things that usually change.

Vector3 defaultPosition = bullet.transform.position;
Quaternion defaultRotation = bullet.transform.rotation;

4. Have a bool variable to determine when the bullet is in use so that it cannot be resued until its no longer in use. We can call this `bool isInUse = false`;
5. Make a **reset** function to **reset** the bullet. Inside the **reset**, all you have to do is to reset those values that **changes** their **default** values when shot and then **disable** the bullet. Also set `isInUse`  to false.
   For example,

void reset{

bullet.transform.position = defaultPosition;

bullet.transform.rotation = defaultRotation;

bullet.SetActive(false);

isInUse =false;

}

6. Create a coroutine function called "WaitForReset" that determines when the bullet should reset. 
   You can reset the bullet based on **distance** it has travedled, how many **seconds** it has been away after it has been shot or when it **collides** with another GameObject. This is up to you to implement. The one I have below will wait for 5 seconds and then reset the GameObject/bullet.

   `IEnumerator WaitForReset() {

   yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

   reset();

   }`
7. To **shoot** a bullet, **Check** if one of the 20 bullets property `isInUse` is `false`, then load the **first** one that returns `false`. If the the current bullet isInUse, go to the next one.  Once you shoot the bullet, call the WaitForReset() function so that the bullet can reset later on.

StartCoroutine(WaitForReset());

This will have happen over and over again without allocating and deallocating memory therefore improving the speed of the game.

**SOLUTION FOR LARGE UNIQUE MODELS** in the scene such as buildings. 
Assuming you have big objects with HQ textures on them, the pooling may not be the best way to go about this.

**Level of Detail** (*LOD*) should be used. So basically you create multiple 3D models for each large GameObject. High detailed object, mid detail, low detailed and really really row detailed polygon.

When you are far from that object, Unity would only show the low detailed 3D model. As soon as you move closer to the object, Unity would automatically swap the 3D model with a high detailed 3D Model. This improves the memory and the speed of the game. To see how to set this up Google "Level of Detail unity" and watch the videos. It requires visual to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Unity will not delete instantiated GameObjects for you. I don't know what kind of level you are talking about, but if it is some kind of endless level you eventually have to take care of memory and might need to delete created GameObjects.

If it is possible to reuse those GameObjects you should have a look at a method called "Object Pooling". Here is an official video tutorial from Unity:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling

Note: This is just a suggestion to sparse information. Depending on your kind of level it might also make sense to not delete the GameObjects at all. For example when you don't want them to dissapear because you can revisit parts of the level and the memory usage is to low to care about. (Activate the stats panel at the Game window in Unity editor.)

Comment: I am talking about 'temple run' kind of game. I presume the game generates new objects when player moves forward.